# Any existing relations between association schemes and matroids

Tags: matroid-theory, association-schemes

Can anyone point out (if any) references which contain any possible links between association schemes and matroids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Section 6.4 in [Network Coding](https://books.google.at/books?id=_JyPg18-XRMC&pg=PT193&lpg=PT193&dq=%22network%20coding%22%20al%20agha&source=bl&ots=8Lh4I-LaGz&sig=fjG_kAYkUG63j_TsEviUphuNDmY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwio2Pyd5qPQAhUH7hoKHdHbALAQ6AEIMzAD#v=onepage&q=%22association%20scheme%22&f=false) and Section 2.3 of [Matroid Applications](https://books.google.at/books?id=uD2H-RAcBpwC&pg=PA58&lpg=PA58&dq=%22association%20scheme%22%20matroid&source=bl&ots=JLcD9v__hb&sig=W7tststOAUguYigv6qupnqYVjHQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwirobf17KPQAhXDXRoKHTyYBrwQ6AEIMjAC#v=onepage&q=%22association%20scheme%22&f=false).

> 1. Al Agha, Khaldoun, ed. Network Coding. John Wiley & Sons, 2012.
> 2. White, Neil. Matroid applications. Vol. 40. Cambridge University Press, 1992.